# Save custom shortcuts

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

is there a way to save the custom shortcuts that I will eventually set in this window:

http://cl.ly/98160fe9cb7b907ad25f

Just wondering, I'll probably have to rewrite a bit of shortcuts for an app, and it would be nice if I could backup these if I need to reformat someday...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom shortcuts are saved in your `~/Library/Preferences/`* folder. If you back that up (which is a good thing to do if you reformat and restore), you'll be good.

*specifically in the `com.apple.universalaccess.plist` file, and `NSUserKeyEquivalents` entries in the .plist preference files of specific applications you set.